# Compiling OpenCV on Raspberry Pi 2

Tags: c++, opencv, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi2

I am compiling OpenCV on a Raspberry 2
and I am jammed on this step,

```
[ 18%] Building CXX object modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/src/cap_ffmpeg.cpp.o
```

with returned a lot of error, I take only 2 of the begining, other of them look the same
but different on `{ CODEC_ID_H264, MKTAG('h', '2', '6', '4') },`

```
In file included from /home/pi/opencv/modules/highgui/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:60:0,
                 from /home/pi/opencv/modules/highgui/src/cap_ffmpeg.cpp:45:
/home/pi/opencv/modules/highgui/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:104:7: error: 'CODEC_ID_H264' was not     declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_H264, MKTAG('H', '2', '6', '4') },
       ^
/home/pi/opencv/modules/highgui/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:105:7: error: 'CODEC_ID_H264' was not     declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_H264, MKTAG('h', '2', '6', '4') },
       ^
```

and the final part is about

```
/home/pi/opencv/modules/highgui/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp: In member function 'double     CvCapture_FFMPEG::get_fps()':
/home/pi/opencv/modules/highgui/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:821:49: error: 'AVStream' has no member named 'r_frame_rate'
     double fps = r2d(ic->streams[video_stream]->r_frame_rate);
                                             ^
In file included from /home/pi/opencv/modules/highgui/src/cap_ffmpeg.cpp:45:0:
/home/pi/opencv/modules/highgui/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp: In function 'int         icv_av_write_frame_FFMPEG(AVFormatContext*, AVStream*, uint8_t*, uint32_t, AVFrame*)':
/home/pi/opencv/modules/highgui/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:1237:72: error: 'avcodec_encode_video'     was not declared in this scope
         out_size = avcodec_encode_video(c, outbuf, outbuf_size, picture);
                                                                    ^
modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/build.make:215: recipe for target     'modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/src/cap_ffmpeg.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: ** [modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/src/cap_ffmpeg.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1823: recipe for target 'modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/all'     failed
make[1]: *** [modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:137: recipe for target 'all' failed
```

Please help me for this while I get stucked on it for a long time after tried few times, thank you

Comment: Or, is there any way I can get a compiled bin for Raspberry Pi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is probably due to the fact you are using the `ffmpeg` from the repositories. When building OpenCV from source it is strongly recommended to build the respective `ffmpeg` version too. Remove any installation of `ffmpeg` and `x264` from your Pi and then do a build.

Check [this guide here](http://www.wiki.xilinx.com/OpenCV+Installation) for more information.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it did

Comment: Glad it worked out. :) Perhaps mark my post as the answer (since it is :D)?

Comment: That doesn't seem to work for me.

When running 

`./configure --enable-shared --disable-static --cross-prefix=arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi- --arch=armv7l --target-os=linux --prefix=<local path>`
(as specified in the link you'v shared)

Im getting this sort of error:
`BEGIN /tmp/ffconf.LHUE6snE.c
    1 int main(void){ return 0; }
END /tmp/ffconf.LHUE6snE.c
arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi-gcc -mcpu= -c -o /tmp/ffconf.kpNuXlt1.o /tmp/ffconf.LHUE6snE.c
./configure: 884: ./configure: arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi-gcc: not found
C compiler test failed.`

Any idea what might work?

Comment: 1)Please don't posts questions in the comments that belong to a separate thread and 2)perhaps it has something to do with the strange compiler you are using? Xilinx is used for FPGAs if I'm not mistaken, it's definitely not the default compiler for the Pi. You have explicitely set it as a `prefix` argument so I assume you know what you are doing.

Comment: Sorry but what do we put in the "local path"? and I'm assuming we have to follow the ARM guide for the RaspberryPi?